# crontab + how to prevent removing the first two lines from crontab

Tags: linux, cron

is it possible to prevent delete the first two lines from linux crontab?

I ask because some other app/script can reinstall the crontab so I want to be sure my first two lines in the crontab are safe

Comment: you may want to consider changing permission and ownership of cron file to prevent other apps from changing it, though that's not a good idea, you might prevent the cron itself to change the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider an application that overwrite crontab entries to be buggy. If you have the opportunity to do so, you should contact the authors of that software and file a bug report.

---

No, there is no way to mark a cron job in the crontab as "protected".  If you load a predefined crontab through

```
$ crontab crontab.txt
```

then it will replace any existing jobs in the current crontab.

The correct way to programmatically add crontab entries is to save the current crontab to a file, update this file and load the crontab back in.  This is what happens when you interactively edit the crontab using `crontab -e` (the `crontab` command does it for you).

In a script, this may be done with

```
# dump the current crontab to file:
crontab -l >/tmp/crontab.txt

# some command to update the /tmp/crontab.txt text file, for example:
cat "$HOME/additional_entries.txt" >>/tmp/crontab.txt

# must also make sure that these entries don't already exist, obviously

# reload the modified crontab, which replaces the old one:
crontab /tmp/crontab.txt
rm -f /tmp/crontab.txt
```